Make Material UI more square?
I'm on Android 14 and it's UI is getting more and more round. Is there a way to make it less round / (almost) completely square? It's probably a personal taste but having almost all boxes with radius 90 looks awful...
EDIT: I mean UI elements like buttons, tabs, pills, etc. and NOT the icons on the home screen.

If you are referring to the app icons in the launcher, there are launchers where you can define the shape like Nova Launcher.

No, I want UI elements (buttons, pills, decks) etc.

AFAIK, UI elements are embedded in framework.apk, and thus root is required to modify them. Unless the manufacturer provides their own extensive theme customization, probably flashing a custom ROM is another alternative.

So, as usuall, I'l have to go to a brand that allows custom roms (and find a rom that allows modifying that…)...

You can use any number of launcher apps.  As mentioned in the comment, Nova works. It is what I use.
Here is the setup screen for the Home Settings.  You can change an awful amount of things both visually and functionally.


No, I want UI elements (buttons, pills, decks) etc. / I already use Nova launcher and, for icons, I try to avoid any nonsese of "adaptive icons" and just use plain-old-regular icons where each icon has distinct shape so it's easier to distinguish them...
